# Add label to UIView subclass

Tags: objective-c, uilabel

I'm trying to add a label programmatically to my UIView subclass.

```
#import "DrawShapes.h"

@implementation DrawShapes

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
}
return self;
}
```

The problem is, I'm not able to use self.view to add a subview. I'm guessing this is because this can only be done in the main class. Is there any workaround?

```
UILabel *lblName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 200, 200, 80)];
lblName.text = @”Admin”;
[self.view addSubview:lblName];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider what `self` means here. It is the class instance itself, right? And what is that class? A `UIView` subclass. So the type of `self` is in fact `UIView`. In other words, `[self addSubview:view]` is quite enough. You're probably used to the `self.view` after working with `UIViewController`s.

Comment: No problem. It has probably happened to all of us.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self addSubview:lblName];
```

try this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use :

```
[self addSubview:lblName];
```